# ASP.NET MVC 4 with Parse Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, parse-platform

I'm currently working on ASP.NET MVC 4 with Parse.com. In order to use Parse data, it needs to have

```
ParseClient.Initialize("Your Application ID", "Your .NET Key");
```

Could you please tell me where do I put this code? I put it inside the `Global.asax` file but when I run the my app, it does not retrieve the data. I used the same code for retrieving data in my console application and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I hope you have put it inside Application_Start() method. That's the right place. You can put a break point at your initialize to check whether it hits or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about putting the `ParseClient.Initialize` in the `Global.asax`. However, in order to retrieve data you need to use another method.

You can find all the information you need here: https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#queries

I cannot help you without more information regarding your database, therefore just use the sample methods and change the values required accordingly to your Parse datbase.